# How to calculate the sum of the datatable column in php

Tags: php, sql, select, datatable

I have a DataTable which has 5 columns:

```
sl, Doctor, Appointments, fees
```

The DataTable contains 4 rows.

I want to show the sum of the fees Column  as "Total fees"

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide your working code, sample code, or additional detail for your specific problem...

Comment: var table = $('#servertable').DataTable();                                                                                                                                     
  table.column( 3 ).data().sum();

  $('#servertable').DataTable( {
    drawCallback: function () {
      var api = this.api();
      api.table().footer().to$().html(
        api.column( 3, {page:'current'} ).data().sum()
      );
    }
  } );                              This is what am copied from bootsrap data table .but i dont understand this and its not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `DataTable` plugin to show tables, then try it to calculate sum

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.column( 4 ).data().sum(); // as fees is your fourth column
```

**More Info:**

http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()#

https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/api.html

For normal database operation try simple query using `SUM` aggregate method

```
SELECT SUM(fees) as 'Total fees' FROM your_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use the `SUM()` function. If your table name is DataTable this is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(fees) as 'Total fees' FROM DataTable
```

Read more at:

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm

Comment: am using the data table

Comment: the downvoter can explain where is the error? I can improve my answer